# Can CSS grid-columns respect the min-width of an item spanning multiple columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

Take the following grid:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [one] minmax(auto, 1fr) [two] minmax(auto, 1fr);
}

.item {
    grid-column: one;
    min-width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

The item behaves as expected: both columns fill the grid, but as the parent gets smaller, the first column does not get any smaller than the min-width of the item, 3rem, while the second column continues to collapse to 0. All good.

Now consider

```css
.item {
    grid-column: one / span 2;
    min-width: 3rem;
}
```

Now all columns collapse to 0. Effectively, 'auto' means 0 in this case (which is not clear from the spec, where it talks about auto as a maximum but not as a minimum).

Here is a codepen that illustrates this behaviour. See how the grey box escapes it's container at smaller screen sizes!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJbMVB?editors=1100

Is there any way to get the grid to respect the min-width of an item spanning multiple columns, whilst still allowing them to expand with the available free space when the grid is larger? Or is the current behaviour to spec (and if so, where does it say so)?

Comment: If you are defining a min-with, should this not be reflected in the `minmax`? https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ELEvOm?editors=1100

Comment: @Paulie_D If you are defining a min-width, minmax(auto, ...) will use the min-width as it's minimum, per spec at least https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#track-sizing

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh I see, you are talking about the second case. I don't know ahead of time what content will be in this grid, so I cannot set min-width on the parent as you suggest.

Comment: If you have min-width on a child that will span all columns, is that not the min-width of the parent?

Comment: @Paulie_D It is not. Here is your codepen modded with an item of 50rem width to make it clear. At smaller sizes, the item escapes the parent. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjWEZp?editors=1100

Comment: Maybe you could post a more detailed demo that illustrates your desired behavior. Also, consider explaining the larger problem. Maybe there's another approach we can take.

Comment: @Michael_B I added a codepen (thanks to @Paulie_D) which explains it pretty well. I'm specifically investigating grids right now so I'm not looking for other suggestions. I'd just like to know if this behaviour is to spec, or if we can expect that it will be fixed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well it appears the answer is: No.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
minmax(min-content, 1fr)
//    OR
minmax(max-content, 1fr)
```

Comment: Of course.

According to spec, minmax(auto, ...) evaluates to minmax(min-content, ...) anyway, so those are the same thing. Max-content is not what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work either. See here, where the grey box escapes the container https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjWEZp?editors=1100